# Javascript counter both buttons are incrementing when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a simple page with an even simpler javaScript counter. I would like the minus and plus signs within each of these three divs to increment and decrement when you click on them. Once they have been clicked they will update the content of the span with the count class.

However, both the minus and subtraction signs are incrementing when I click on them. I implemented a for loop that would check the value to prevent this but it didnt work. The counter is also giving me negative values what can I do to fix this?

```js
const ctaLabels = document.querySelectorAll(".cta");
    Array.from(ctaLabels).forEach(function (label) {
      label.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const countSpan = label.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".count");
        if (label.textContent === "+") {
          countSpan.textContent = parseInt(countSpan.textContent) + 1;
        } else {
          countSpan.textContent = parseInt(countSpan.textContent) - 1;
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
.cta {
color: white;
background: blue;
font: var(--font-variant-6);
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
transition: all 0.15s linear;
}

.cta:hover {
background: blue;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0.15s linear;
}
```

```html
<section id="attendees">
        <div class="container">
          <h3 class="title">How many people should we be expecting?</h3>
          <div class="field-group --advanced">
            <div class="field --counter --required">
              <div class="label">Men:</div>
              <div class="input">
                <div>
                  <span class="count">0</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="actions">
                <label for="" class="cta">
                  <span>&minus;</span>
                </label>
                <label for="" class="cta">
                  <span>&plus;</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              
              <label for="" class="field__label">Men:</label>
              <input
                required
                id="men"
                name="men"
                type="number"
                placeholder="0"
                class="field__input"
              />
              
            </div>
            <div class="field --counter --required">
              <div class="label">Women:</div>
              <div class="input">
                <div>
                  <span class="count">0</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="actions">
                <label for="" class="cta">
                  <span>&minus;</span>
                </label>
                <label for="" class="cta">
                  <span>&plus;</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              
              <label for="" class="field__label">Women:</label>
              <input
                required
                id="women"
                name="women"
                type="number"
                placeholder="0"
                class="field__input"
              />
              
            </div>
            <div class="field --counter --required">
              <div class="label">Children:</div>
              <div class="input">
                <div>
                  <span class="count">0</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="actions">
                <label for="" class="cta">
                  <span>&minus;</span>
                </label>
                <label for="" class="cta">
                  <span>&plus;</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              
              <label for="" class="field__label">Children:</label>
              <input
                required
                id="children"
                name="children"
                type="number"
                placeholder="0"
                class="field__input"
              />
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: have you try `console.log(label.textContent)`? does it log `-` or `+` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use trim function to check whether to - or +, because text content contains space also

```js
const ctaLabels = document.querySelectorAll(".cta");
    Array.from(ctaLabels).forEach(function (label) {
      label.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const countSpan = label.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".count");
        if (label.textContent.trim() == "+") {
          countSpan.textContent = parseInt(countSpan.textContent) + 1;
        } else {
          countSpan.textContent = parseInt(countSpan.textContent) - 1;
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
.cta {
color: white;
background: blue;
font: var(--font-variant-6);
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
transition: all 0.15s linear;
margin:5px;
}

.cta:hover {
background: blue;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0.15s linear;
}
```

```html
<section id="attendees">
        <div class="container">
          <h3 class="title">How many people should we be expecting?</h3>
          <div class="field-group --advanced">
            <div class="field --counter --required">
              <div class="label">Men:</div>
              <div class="input">
                <div>
                  <span class="count">0</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="actions">
                <button class="cta">
                  <span>&minus;</span>
                </button>
                <button  class="cta">
                  &plus;
                </button>
              </div>
              
              <label for="" class="field__label">Men:</label>
              <input
                required
                id="men"
                name="men"
                type="number"
                placeholder="0"
                class="field__input"
              />
              
            </div>
            <div class="field --counter --required">
              <div class="label">Women:</div>
              <div class="input">
                <div>
                  <span class="count">0</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="actions">
                <label for="" class="cta">
                  <span>&minus;</span>
                </label>
                <label for="" class="cta">
                  <span>&plus;</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              
              <label for="" class="field__label">Women:</label>
              <input
                required
                id="women"
                name="women"
                type="number"
                placeholder="0"
                class="field__input"
              />
              
            </div>
            <div class="field --counter --required">
              <div class="label">Children:</div>
              <div class="input">
                <div>
                  <span class="count">0</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="actions">
                <label for="" class="cta">
                  <span>&minus;</span>
                </label>
                <label for="" class="cta">
                  <span>&plus;</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              
              <label for="" class="field__label">Children:</label>
              <input
                required
                id="children"
                name="children"
                type="number"
                placeholder="0"
                class="field__input"
              />
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to trim the textContent.

```
 if (label.textContent.trim() === "+") {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are checking `label.textContent`, but looking at the structure of your html, there is also a `span` nested under the `label` tag. So `label.textContent` will never be +/- and your if statment will always go on the else branch and decrement the number.

You should change that if statement to check for something like this:

```
label.querySelector('span').textContent
```

Or you could remove the `span` from inside the `label`